# How to fix Sendkey Alt Tab that is Not Working Anymore

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I want to make some auto fill form from excel to web page. First I try to switch from Excel to web page by click Alt+Tab.  I used this code Send Keys ("%{TAB}%"). It's work fine in that day, but when i will continue my program in next day, the code is not working anymore.
(Note 
I don't use code
IE.navigate URL 
from excel to access web page , because that page is child link and i don't know the address)

I work in excel 2010

I used this code

```
Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}%")
```

How to fix that error or if any another code to switch from excel to webpage.

Comment: You probably need `"%{TAB}"`, not `"%{TAB}%"`. How can you be sure which window you'll land on after sending `Alt+Tab` though? That sounds unpredictable to me. You may want to check the [`AppActivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement) statement.

Comment: "%{TAB}" still is not working. For your asked "How can you be sure which window you'll land on after sending Alt+Tab though?" It's work for one day but error in another day. This my full Auto fill webform Dim test As Worksheet
Set test = ActiveSheet
Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")
Aplication.SendKeys ("{CapsLock}")
Application.SendKeys test.Cells(2, 3).Value

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Alt+Tab to switch window, use this code, it works for me

```
  Application.SendKeys "%{TAB}", True
```